# Embedded UIPageController child VC has wrong frame origin

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, ios-autolayout, uicontainerview

I am trying to create a layout element like below in the middle of a page and leverage `UIPageViewController` to do it.

[image: Desired layout]

I embedded a `UIPageViewController` in a container view. The contents of the card element have a height determined by AutoLayout, and stretch horizontally towards the margins, with the card having a max width after which it stays centered.  However I'm running into a strange problem. When I set the VC for the card element to be the contents of my `UIPageViewController`, the individual page gets mostly sized correctly, but its origin is outside the bounds of the pageVC's content view.

I recreated the problem in a very small test project. Here is the storyboard and relevant constraints:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pageController: UIPageViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageView") else { return }
        pageController.setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let dest = segue.destination as? UIPageViewController {
            pageController = dest
        }
    }

}

class SinglePageViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

}
```

And here is what I am actually getting:

[image]

I tried setting `view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]` instead of `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in `SinglePageViewController`, and that gives it correct leading, trailing, and width constraints, but then I can't get the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height: self.height = 0` constraint to go away. There are no system constraints that account for the origin misplacement, so I have no idea how to debug further. All the views higher up in the hierarchy have height 0, and all the views farther down are placed correctly. If I embed the `SinglePageViewController` directly in the container view, it lays out perfectly, but if I put the `UIPageViewController` in between, it breaks.

Why doesn't the `UIPageViewController` constrain the pages inside it to match its view's bounds? Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // don't do this
    //view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

}
```

When views are instantiated from Storyboards they are loaded with appropriate resizing masks... the "Root" view of a view controller ***needs*** `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `true` in order for the layout to work properly.

Removing that line may get you where you need to be, but I think you have a couple constraints setup incorrectly.

Here's how the Storyboard I set up looks:

[image]

Then, using this code:

```
//
//  EmbeddedPageViewViewController.swift
//  Created by Don Mag on 5/21/20.
//

import UIKit

class EmbeddedPageViewViewController: UIViewController {

    var pageController: UIPageViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageView") else { return }
        pageController.setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let dest = segue.destination as? UIPageViewController {
            pageController = dest
        }
    }

}

class SinglePageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var bkgView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bkgView.backgroundColor = .white
        bkgView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        bkgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        bkgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        bkgView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        bkgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.35

    }

}
```

I get this result:

[image]

The main view's background color is set to "cantaloupe" to make it easy to see the frame of the `UIContainerView`.

Rotated to landscape orientation:

[image]

The width maxes out at 325 and it stays centered.

For reference, here's how it looks without setting the view's background to white:

[image]

And here's the source to my Storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="hya-IX-JpL">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Embedded Page View View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="TRC-Gf-9JR">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="hya-IX-JpL" customClass="EmbeddedPageViewViewController" customModule="PassBackNavController" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="gkJ-Gz-CPw">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <containerView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="IRh-01-Go2">
                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="270" width="359" height="128"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="GT3-zg-F9u"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue destination="tRW-tL-JaM" kind="embed" id="DRB-mh-M2m"/>
                                </connections>
                            </containerView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.83234566450000003" blue="0.47320586440000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="IRh-01-Go2" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="qBw-JJ-Fx5" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="Aqh-1J-Wli"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="IRh-01-Go2" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="gkJ-Gz-CPw" secondAttribute="centerY" id="NLG-5N-8Lb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="qBw-JJ-Fx5" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="IRh-01-Go2" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="oDL-2p-roM"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="qBw-JJ-Fx5"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dnU-Gs-r2b" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="119" y="131"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Single Page View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="L0K-o3-YNb">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="PageView" id="cfk-9g-Gkj" customClass="SinglePageViewController" customModule="PassBackNavController" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="7CL-c5-Z9a">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="200"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nC5-Ym-QUo">
                                <rect key="frame" x="25" y="12" width="325" height="176"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="umo-Tg-dpR">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="78" width="285" height="20.5"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.075549371539999993" green="0.79593962429999998" blue="0.99987417460000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="umo-Tg-dpR" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="nC5-Ym-QUo" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="HXw-12-L1h"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" priority="750" constant="325" id="Tfm-wt-KFB"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="umo-Tg-dpR" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="by3-Y5-AqR"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="umo-Tg-dpR" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="nC5-Ym-QUo" secondAttribute="centerY" id="fIW-R2-QXc"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.97619122270000003" green="0.97633117439999995" blue="0.97616070509999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="nC5-Ym-QUo" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="7CL-c5-Z9a" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="ASL-q5-MnJ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nC5-Ym-QUo" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="7CL-c5-Z9a" secondAttribute="centerX" id="O2h-f7-lBG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nC5-Ym-QUo" firstAttribute="leading" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="7CL-c5-Z9a" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="RWx-xc-AnB"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="nC5-Ym-QUo" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="gJ0-QG-ApQ"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="nC5-Ym-QUo" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="mEx-VN-uJ4"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="QrT-IP-grh"/>
                    </view>
                    <size key="freeformSize" width="375" height="200"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="bkgView" destination="nC5-Ym-QUo" id="dx9-da-bUg"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Lfo-H7-oVB" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="884" y="275"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Page View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="jMx-mM-wG7">
            <objects>
                <pageViewController autoresizesArchivedViewToFullSize="NO" transitionStyle="pageCurl" navigationOrientation="horizontal" spineLocation="min" id="tRW-tL-JaM" sceneMemberID="viewController"/>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="xla-ir-fR9" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="897" y="38"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me because the content inside of the card is supposed to determine the height. I don't want to constrain the container view to a constant height, it's supposed to resize vertically with the content. That's why I was playing with the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`.

Comment: @NewShelbyWoo - ok, that will be difficult to do using a `UIPageViewController`. Are each of your "pages" going to (potentially) have different heights? So you want the container view's height to change as you move from page to page?

Comment: Each page within one page controller will not have different heights, but I'm reusing this component for different types of content, so the same element lower down on the page will have a different height

Comment: @NewShelbyWoo - do you know the height of the "page views" at design time? Or will you not know them until run-time?

Comment: @NewShelbyWoo - take a look at "Example 3" in this project: https://github.com/DonMag/AutosizeContainer ... see if that's what you're trying to do.